# Como hacer una consulta de 4 colecciones en MongoDB y NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

es la primera vez que publico espero y no confundirlos, estoy intentando hacer join con 4 colecciones (trips, routes, shapes y stop_times), el objetivo es obtener el siguiente request en nodejs, con mi siguiente conexión y consultas:

```
const getLineasFromMongoGTFS = async (params) => {
  const url = `mongodb://${mongoDbUsername}:${mongoDbPassword}@${mongoServerAddress}:27017`;

  const client = new MongoClient(url, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  
  let pipeline = [
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "routes",
        localField: "route_id",
        foreignField: "route_id",
        as: "routes"
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        route_id: params.idBusSAE,
      },
    },
    {
      $limit: 1,
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "stop_times",
        localField: "trip_id",
        foreignField: "trip_id",
        as: "stops"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "shapes",
        localField: "shape_id",
        foreignField: "shape_id",
        as: "shapes"
      }
    }
  ]

  try {
    console.log (`Intentando conectar a ${url}`)
    await client.connect();
    console.log("Conectado");

    const database = client.db(mongoDbName);
    const collection = database.collection("TRIPS_GTFS");
    console.log (`filtrando por: ${JSON.stringify(pipeline)} `);
    const stops = await collection.aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
        
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stops));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log (`Error al intentar consultar a Mongo ${err}`);
    return err;
  } finally {
    console.log ("cerrando conexión ...");
    await client.close();
  }
};
```

este resultado mandarlo a otra .js que obtendrá el response:

```
/** GTFS **/
const parseAndCreateObjectGTFS = async (params) => {
  console.log("DetalleLineasGTFS!")
  let response = {
    header: createObjectHeader(200),
    result: formatResponseGTFS(await getLineasFromMongoGTFS(params))
  }
  return response;
}

const formatResponseGTFS= (data) => {
  let busLine = [];
  let getColorAndDescBusLine = getColorAndDescription([data?.ida, data?.vuelta]);
  let eachBusLine = {
    idBusSAE: data?.linsae ?? null,
    color: getColorAndDescBusLine.color ?? null,
    distance: data?.distancia ?? null,
    outTrip: getTrip(data?.ida, getColorAndDescBusLine.color ?? null, data?.linsae ?? null),
    backTrip: getTrip(data?.vuelta, getColorAndDescBusLine.color ?? null, data?.linsae ?? null),
    desLocalCompany: null,
    scale: data?.escala ?? null,
    idBusLine: data?.linsae ?? null,
    localCompany: null,
    geographic_data_structure: {
      initial_map_coordinates: [data?.medlon, data?.medlat],
    },
    descBusLine: getColorAndDescBusLine.name ?? null,
  };
  busLine.push(eachBusLine);
  return { busLine };
};

/**
 * Get the color and the information for busLine
 * @param {Array} trips 
 */
const getColorAndDescription = (trips) => {
  let object = {};
  trips.forEach((eachTrip) => {
    eachTrip?.features.forEach((eachFeature) => {
      if (eachFeature?.geometry?.type === "MultiLineString") {
        if (eachFeature?.properties?.color !== "") {
          object.color = eachFeature?.properties?.color ?? null;
          object.name = eachFeature?.properties?.name ?? null;
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  });
  return object;
};

/**
 * 
 * @param {Array} trip 
 * @param {String} color 
 * @param {Number} idBusLine 
 * @returns 
 */
const getTrip = (trip, color, idBusLine) => {
  let features = [];
  trip?.features.forEach((eachFeature) => {
    let feature = {
      ...eachFeature,
      properties: {
        node: eachFeature?.properties?.nodo ?? null,
        idBusStop: eachFeature?.properties?.id ?? null,
        idBusSAE: eachFeature?.properties?.idsae ?? null,
        color: color,
        desBusStop: eachFeature?.properties?.nombre ?? null,
        idBusLine: idBusLine,
        busLineCrossing: eachFeature?.properties?.enlace ?? null,
      },
    };
    features.push(feature);
  });

  let tripCreated = {
    features: features,
    type: trip?.type ?? "",
  };
  return tripCreated;
};
```

Pero al intentar mostrarlo en mi postman no obtengo el resultado.

Mis colecciones son las siguientes:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNRY5.png

El resultado que tiene que mostrar es el siguiente para estas colecciones:

```
Response:
{
    "header": {
        "code": 100,
        "message": "Detalle de Líneas Obtenido",
        "status": "OK"
    },
    "result": {
        "busLine": [
            {
                "idBusSAE": "3",
                "color": "#a44918",
                "distance": "1,88",
                "outTrip": {
                    "features": [
                        {
                            "type": "Feature",
                            "properties": {
                                "node": null,
                                "idBusStop": "3",
                                "idBusSAE": null,
                                "color": "#a44918",
                                "desBusStop": null,
                                "idBusLine": "3",
                                "busLineCrossing": null
                            },
                            "geometry": {
                                "type": "MultiLineString",
                                "coordinates": [
                                    [
                                        [
                                            -4.1036296946143,
                                            40.946342961669
                                        ],
                                        [
                                            -4.1033288327603,
                                            40.946111631108
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            },
                            "style": {
                                "fill": "red",
                                "stroke-width": 3,
                                "fill-opacity": 0.6
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Feature",
                            "properties": {
                                "node": "31",
                                "idBusStop": "31",
                                "idBusSAE": "31",
                                "color": "#a44918",
                                "desBusStop": "Marqués De Lozoya",
                                "idBusLine": "3",
                                "busLineCrossing": ""
                            },
                            "geometry": {
                                "type": "Point",
                                "coordinates": [
                                    -4.1036,
                                    40.9462
                                ]
                            }
                        }
```

--- routes.txt---
route_id,agency_id,route_short_name,route_long_name,route_type,route_color,route_text_color
0ef49e6f,1,84,San Pedrito Penuelas - Paseos De San Miguel EVC,3,049684,ffffff
149d6078,1,123,El Colorado - Ejido Modelo,3,b10086,ffffff
1583cb76,1,67,Tanque - El Nabo,3,ad0101,ffffff
15eebee4,1,85,Terminal De Autobuses Taq - Pueblito Cam,3,4e0963,ffffff
1ca7282e,1,77,Universidad Cuauhtemoc - Col 20 De Enero EVC,3,C9500E,ffffff
217fd397,1,131,Cto Vistana - Av De La Luz - Uaq Vistana Ote A Pte EVC,3,613FA6,ffffff
22670cd9,1,45,Terminal De Autobuses Taq - La Loma,3,A72051,ffffff
28130034,1,83,Rancho Bellavista - Col Sergio Villasenor EVC,3,ad0101,ffffff
31bfb449,1,66,Tanque - Juriquilla Km 15 EVC,3,cc9b00,ffffff
335a2612,1,69,Santa Barbara - Col San Pedro,3,A72051,ffffff
35b469d6,1,121,Terminal De Autobuses Taq - Parque,3,4e0963,ffffff
37f6665a,1,136,Terminal De Autobuses Taq - Puertas De San,3,b10086,ffffff
3c4c221e,1,50,Mercado De La Cruz - Col 10 De Abril EVC,3,0071ca,ffffff
3c7ec80e,1,138,Hospital Imss El Marques - Bernardo Quintana,3,ad0101,ffffff
3f13b8ae,1,133,Plaza Patio - La Pradera,3,cc9b00,ffffff
424123fc,1,78,Mercado Escobedo - El Pozo EVC,3,ad0101,ffffff
55d12557,1,27,Paseos De San Miguel - Fraccionamiento EVC,3,b10086,ffffff
59a651fa,1,59,Fraccionamiento Vistana - Col Praderas,3,ce5504,ffffff
5c1c0c10,1,81,Valle De Santiago - Lazaro Cardenas EVC,3,049684,ffffff
5f1fc681,1,24,La Pradera - Boulevares Del Cimatario,3,049684,ffffff
6445202a,1,7,Boulevares Del Cimatario - Fracc Vistana EVC,3,cc9b00,ffffff
6803583a,1,51,Rancho San Pedro - Boulevares Del Cimatario,3,ce5504,ffffff
68f7d669,1,L04,Penal - Fracc Santuarios,3,ce5504,ffffff
6b9f5117,1,69B,Santa Barbara - Real Solare,3,cc9b00,ffffff
6c263d5b,1,37,Los Olvera - La Canada,3,b10086,ffffff
729130b3,1,12,Chedraui - Azucenas,3,613FA6,ffffff
74ee9d36,1,53,San Jose De Los Olvera - La Pradera EVC,3,0071ca,ffffff
76e1ee47,1,41,Vista Azul - Paseos Del Pedregal,3,cc9b00,ffffff
77c022b2,1,94,La Canada - Fracc Piramides,3,0071ca,ffffff

---shapes.txt---
shape_id,shape_pt_lat,shape_pt_lon,shape_pt_sequence
860746228,20.66304,-100.47106,1
860746228,20.66304,-100.47106,2
860746228,20.66304,-100.47106,3
860746228,20.66242,-100.4708,4
860746228,20.66239,-100.4708,5
860746228,20.66167,-100.47275,6
860746228,20.6614,-100.47296,7
860746228,20.66002,-100.47394,8
860746228,20.66,-100.47393,9
860746228,20.65909,-100.4725,10
860746228,20.65905,-100.47247,11
860746228,20.656549,-100.471559,12
860746228,20.656549,-100.471559,13
860746228,20.65454,-100.47083,14
860746228,20.6545,-100.47075,15
860746228,20.65526,-100.46933,16
860746228,20.65593,-100.46805,17
860746228,20.65593,-100.46802,18
860746228,20.65436,-100.46611,19

--- stop_times.txt ---
trip_id,stop_id,stop_sequence,arrival_time,departure_time,timepoint
1,17279542,1,05:00:00,05:00:00,1
1,17208827,2,05:00:00,05:00:00,0
1,17208829,3,05:01:00,05:01:00,0
1,17209080,4,05:02:00,05:02:00,0
1,17209079,5,05:03:00,05:03:00,0
1,17279545,6,05:03:00,05:03:00,0
1,17209082,7,05:04:00,05:04:00,0
1,17279182,8,05:05:00,05:05:00,0
1,17207808,9,05:06:00,05:06:00,0
1,17207806,10,05:08:00,05:08:00,0
1,17207807,11,05:08:00,05:08:00,0
1,17208826,12,05:09:00,05:09:00,1
1,17208421,13,05:09:00,05:09:00,0
1,17278332,14,05:10:00,05:10:00,0
1,17208823,15,05:12:00,05:12:00,0
1,17208419,16,05:13:00,05:13:00,0
1,17208821,17,05:13:00,05:13:00,0
1,17208824,18,05:14:00,05:14:00,0
1,17207782,19,05:15:00,05:15:00,0
1,17207780,20,05:15:00,05:15:00,0
1,17207811,21,05:16:00,05:16:00,0
1,17207812,22,05:16:00,05:16:00,0

--- trips ---
trip_id,block_id,route_id,service_id,direction_id,shape_id
1,,0ef49e6f,2,0,860746228
2,,0ef49e6f,2,0,860746228
3,,0ef49e6f,2,0,860746228
4,,0ef49e6f,2,0,860746228
5,,0ef49e6f,2,0,860746228
6,,0ef49e6f,2,0,860746228
7,,0ef49e6f,2,1,860746229
8,,0ef49e6f,2,0,860746228
9,,0ef49e6f,2,1,860746229
10,,0ef49e6f,2,0,860746228
11,,0ef49e6f,2,0,860746228
12,,0ef49e6f,2,1,860746229
13,,0ef49e6f,2,0,860746228
14,,0ef49e6f,2,1,860746229
15,,0ef49e6f,2,0,860746228
16,,0ef49e6f,2,1,860746229

--- stops.txt ---
stop_id,stop_name,stop_lat,stop_lon
17279542,"Avenida San Rafael, 5123",20.662948,-100.471069
17208827,San Rafael y San Samael,20.662362,-100.470961
17208829,San Uriel y San Samael,20.661472,-100.472956
17209080,San Gabriel y San  Samael,20.659858,-100.473834
17209079,"San Ariel, 5289",20.657947,-100.472083
17279545,"Avenida San Miguel, 6008",20.65742,-100.471879
17209082,San Ariel y San Daniel,20.654546,-100.470635
17279182,Calle San Rafael y Eduardo Loarca,20.655818,-100.467968
17207808,"San Ariel, 5003",20.654539,-100.46639
17207806,Plan de San Luis y Solidaridad,20.653762,-100.462567
17207807,Plan de San Luis y Calle 13,20.655077,-100.461506
17208826,Plan de San Luis y Tomás Urbina,20.656321,-100.460483
17208421,Plan de San Luis y Condominio C9,20.656974,-100.459986
17278332,"Avenida Plan de San Luis, 6031",20.659441,-100.458209
17208823,Popocatépetl y Maguey,20.659689,-100.455523
17208419,Popocatépetl y Kilimanjaro,20.65812,-100.453291
17208821,Popocátepetl  y Cerro de la Tinaja,20.657408,-100.45224
17208824,Cerro de Sangremal y Popocátepetl,20.655495,-100.450936
17207782,Popocátepetl y Montes Escandinavos,20.653596,-100.450802

Alguna idea :(

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir como texto, un documento de cada colección en tu pregunta? Pon el nombre de la colección y un documento asociado a la misma. Haz clic en [edit] para actualizar tu pregunta. Saludos